# asp.net vb gridview coulours based on previous row

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` displaying results from sql server, all values are supposed to follow on the previous value e.g. 3373 must be before 3372. I need to colour the row on the gridview as soon as the value does not follow the previous value. Sometimes the values are missing so I need to identify if a value is missing or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the OnRowDataBound event to store the last value and compare. Something like this:

```
Private _lastRowValue As Integer =  -1 

Protected  Sub OnGridViewRowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) 
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
      If _lastRowValue <> -1 Then
          ' read current row value, compare and then format, e.g. like this 
          e.Row.Cells(1).Text = "<i>" + e.Row.Cells(1).Text + "</i>"
      End If
      _lastRowValue = ... ' read value from cell 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Is it possible to send the response in VB ? I'm rather new to this.

Comment: You can always use a converter like this http://www.dotnetspider.com/convert/CSharp-To-Vb.aspx. Otherwise add the VB.NET tag (as I did for you).